# AWS IAM policy issue: unable to permit all but RunInstances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We are struggling to create an IAM policy that permits all EC2 actions EXCEPT RunInstances.  This is to prevent an API key compromise from launching unauthorized instances.  We tried it both with and without the EC2 allow * because I'm not clear if NotAction implies all actions.

With the NotAction in place I cannot provision EBS volumes (below).  Do we need to converge the EC2 allow * and Notaction Runinstances into the same policy section?

EC2 All permissions:

"Action": "ec2:*",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": "*",

and then a second policy that denies RunInstances (from [previous IAM policy answer on similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465622/how-to-allow-aws-user-to-see-but-not-launch-start-or-stop-instances)

{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "NotAction": [
        "ec2:RunInstances*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   * aws_ebs_volume[ip-10-140-10-132.volume15] action create

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com [2014-06-26T18:17:53+00:00] WARN: ##### RightAws::Ec2 returned an error: 403 Forbidden

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com `UnauthorizedOperation`You are not authorized to perform this operation.fcd71112-db50-4102-9855-a46749574de9 #####

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com [2014-06-26T18:17:53+00:00] WARN: ##### RightAws::Ec2 request: https://us-east-1.ec2.amazonaws.com:443/?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Action=DescribeVolumes&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-06-26T18%3A17%3A53.000Z&Version=2012-06-15&Signature=cRMAxfs3RP0R9rlQeb7JU9zYeey8L3CWQI2Pkj2o3V0%3D ####

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com ================================================================================

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com Error executing action `create` on resource 'aws_ebs_volume[ip-10-140-10-132.volume15]'

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com ================================================================================

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com RightAws::AwsError

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com ------------------

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com Cookbook Trace:

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com ---------------

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:138:in `currently_attached_volume'

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:26:in `block in class_from_file'

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com Resource Declaration:

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com ---------------------

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cook_aws/recipes/ebs.rb

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  26:   aws_ebs_volume node['w2o']['ebs']['volume_name'] do

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  27:     action [:create, :attach]

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  28:     aws_access_key node['aws']['access_key_id']

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  29:     aws_secret_access_key node['aws']['secret_access_key']

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  30:     device node['w2o']['ebs']['ebs_device']

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  31:     size node['w2o']['ebs']['ebs_mount_size']

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  32:

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  33:     # specify piops if present in node attr

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  34:     if node['w2o']['ebs']['ebs_piops'] > 0

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  35:       piops node['w2o']['ebs']['ebs_piops']

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  36:       volume_type 'io1'

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  37:     end

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com  38:

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com Compiled Resource:

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com ------------------

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/cook_aws/recipes/ebs.rb:26:in `from_file'

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com aws_ebs_volume("ip-10-140-10-132.volume15") do

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   action [:create, :attach]

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   retries 0

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   retry_delay 2

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   cookbook_name "cook_aws"

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   recipe_name "ebs"

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   aws_access_key "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   aws_secret_access_key "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   device "/dev/xvdf"

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   size 50

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com end

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com [2014-06-26T18:17:53+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com [2014-06-26T18:17:53+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com [2014-06-26T18:17:53+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com Chef Client failed. 2 resources updated

ec2-54-196-184-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com [2014-06-26T18:17:54+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

Answer (score 1):

Spent an hour with a trial account and the IAM simulator to get:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "NotAction": [
            "ec2:RunInstances*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "autoscaling:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Posting in case this is useful to someone, you can put whatever actions you want under NotAction

Comment: Careful - that policy will allow users to perform any action in the whole AWS account other than ec2:RunInstances. For example, creating RDS instances, elasticache clusters and even full access to IAM which allows them to change their own permissions. They would then be able to change the policy to allow ec2:RunInstances anyway.

Comment: TYVM will retry with  "Resource": "ec2:*" instead, I did not think of the IAM hole.  The RDS thing is okay in our case.  But the IAM hole needs to be fixed!  I will attach another policy that has IAM Deny *.